# Why is Steins;Gate in the Beta Attractor Field?

Tags: steins-gate

As stated in the [Wiki](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Attractor_Field#Beta), the *Steins;Gate* world line is in

> the Beta attractor field. In the Beta attractor field, the final convergent point is World War 3.

However, they prevent

> WW3 by making sure the thesis will be destroyed.

The question is, if Steins Gate is in

> the Beta attractor field, wouldn't it lead to WW3? If WW3 doesn't happen, shouldn't Steins;Gate be in another attractor field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Steins;Gate World Line is not in the Beta Attractor Field.

While the final result of the Beta Attractor Field (World Lines 1% to 1.99%) convergence is WW3 which is fought over Makise Kurisu's time travel thesis, Steins;Gate (1.048596%) is the only exception because the thesis is destroyed (and thus time travel doesn't exist in that World Line).

At the beginning of the final chapter of the VN and episode 23 of the anime, Suzuha herself had told Okabe that the Steins;Gate World Line is not bounded by any attractor field.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't in the Beta Attractor Field. It's being separated from any attractor field (maybe has its own, since there are few world lines too close to the Steins Gate and repeating its events, for example, 1.048599, the alternate story of *Robotics;Notes* from manga Legacy Revival, or the "R" line from the movie).

According to the official documentation for the world lines in Amadeus' Script, released after *Steins;Gate 0*, 1.048596 is in "Steins Gate" section. An interesting thing, that there is 1.049326 world line, which belongs to mysterious X Attractor Field.

Source: [Imgur gallery of translated official documentation to all *Steins;Gate* VNs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJb4Y.jpg)

Comment: If possible, cite relevant sources in your answer.

Comment: @W. Are here you are: https://m.imgur.com/gallery/R9MXNod

Comment: You can edit and include it in your answer and cite as to where it was found (chapter/volume/episode etc.). I'm not familiar with the terms used so I might change the meaning of your post :)

Answer (score 0):

They used thread as an example for world lines, all are slightly different.

Attractor Field Example:
http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Attractor_Field

But when thread frays and unravels strands can get separated, thus creating a divergent would line.

[image: fraying example]

Answer (score 0):

Although the Steins;Gate world line has a divergence number 1.048596, the Steins;Gate world line is between the 2 attractor fields - the alpha and the beta.

This allows it to not converge to either of the converging points of the alpha and beta attractor fields, in this case, Mayuri dying/SERN dystopia or WW3, and therefore the Steins;Gate world line can have a different future than either of them, i.e, a peaceful one.